# svcutil ignores out paramter of async WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, svcutil.exe, out

I have a service WCF interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "net.pipe://QFX_DLL/TradingService")]
public interface IGenericTradingInterface  {

    [OperationContract]
    void GetServerInformation(out ServerAttributes attributes);
}
```

The host for this is up and running correct. I create the client proxy object with svcutil as follows:

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config net.pipe://localhost/QFX_DLL/mex /async /tcv:Version35
```

The generated proxy for the async call looks like this:

```
public void GetServerInformationAsync()
{
    this.GetServerInformationAsync(null);
}
```

As you see, the out parameter attributes is completely missing! The non-async methods look fine.
With this declaration of GetServerInformationAsync I can't get the result back.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The out parameter (and any results) will be in the EventArgs class which is passed to the event which is fired when GetServerInformation completes (likely GetServerInformationCompleted). The property name will be either Result (which is likely the case in an operation returning only 1 value) or the parameter name (attributes).

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too, but when I want to read from the result like this: Console.WriteLine("ServerInfo Time: {0}", e.Result.CurrentTime.ToString()); then I get an excpetion: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException, so I thought this is due to the missing parameter.

Comment: The solution is, that one cannot have get and set on the fields of struct passed to a WCF method. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Check the `InnerException` property of thhe `TargetInvocationException`, it should give you more information on the problem. And you certainly can have getters/setters on types passed on WCF methods, are you having any other issues?